# give an onclick function to be executed to every element with a certain class

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How would i go about making something like this - i have multiple elements with a certain class and i would like this to happen:

element1 - onclick fires someFunction(13);

element2 - onclick fires someFunction(27);

element3 - onclick fires someFunction(81);

i am loading these elements in dynamically so i can't put it manually into my js file. I also can't give them an onclick as i load them with php.
I am looking for a purely  js answer so please no jQuery.

Comment: Are they just three elements? If not, what should be the value of y in someFunction(y) of elementN?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or whatever to understand your problem better. Reading your question, it seems like you could use events delegation to solve your problem.

Comment: @davidmatas the question is allready answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is giving the elements a data-attribute with the parameter for the function you want to run:

```
<div class="someclass" data-parameter="12">
<div class="someclass" data-parameter="13">
<div class="someclass" data-parameter="14">
```

and then run this:

```
function setMyHandler(){
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].onclick = function(){ myFunction(this.data.parameter); };
   }
}
```

Here is a link for data attributes: [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

And here is a snipplet to see the simple version of it in action:

```js
function setMyHandler(){
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass');
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].onclick = function(){window.alert(this.dataset.somevalue);};
   }
}

setMyHandler();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

div.someclass {
  margin: 2%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #80bfff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
}

div.someclass:hover {
  background: #3399ff;
}
```

```html
<div class="someclass" data-somevalue="13">  </div>

<div class="someclass" data-somevalue="14">  </div>

<div class="someclass" data-somevalue="15">  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function setMyHandler(){
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
   for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      elements[i].onclick = function(){};
   }
}
```

But I would be better advised to use you event delegate. Set Handler on root element. And checking event.target. http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1**
In your PHP code, create your elements with onclick tags, with intended input into the function.

```
<div class="someclass" onclick="someFunction(1)"></div>
```

**Approach #2**
When the page loads, iterate through all elements with your given classname and attach listeners to them. For this approach to work, the divs must have the numbers which will be entered in SomeFunction included in arbitrary tags.

```
<div data="13" > =) </div>

window.onload = function() {
  for (var i =0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("classname").; i++){
      var Div = document.getElementsByClassName("classname")[i];
      Div.addEventListener("click", function(){
        someFunction(Div.data);
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks does this work with any arbitrary tag?  and do theese tags disturb any other code?

Comment: Yes, this works with any arbitrarily named tag. No, they should not disturb any other code!

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate events by attaching event listener to parent element. To get the target element you can use `event.target`

Here's the sample code how you can achieve it:

```
var parentElement = document.querySelector("#parent");
    parentElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var currentTarget = event.target;
        if (currentTarget.tagName === "LI") { // If you want LI to be clickable
            currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = "#eee";
            currentTarget.style.color = "#606060";
        }
    });
```

Here's the jsfiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/dx8Lye29/

Comment: Thanks a lot i combined yours and @jsm 's answers :)

Comment: Since i can't post another new question i'll have to ask you here - how could i for example get the index of the clicked element within the parent? like if i clicked on the 3rd element it would return number 3?

Comment: I have made an improvement on existing fiddle. Checkout link: https://jsfiddle.net/dx8Lye29/7/

For a generic (recommended) approach, checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dx8Lye29/9/